# Are SSR Relays suitable for inductive and capacitive loads?

Tags: relay, switching, solid-state-relay, triac, inductive

I want to knowingly buy a cheap knockoff SSR Realy from some online sellers. The SSR Relay is advertised as not to be used for inductive or capacitive loads.

My application is switching on or off a couple of 90W rated florescent lamp using either a starter or a electronic ballast, which I assume they are inductive loads?

Can you please explain if the SSR Relays are not good for such load types or just the seller knows his knockoff part can not handle such loads?

What if we use a genuine expensive SSR relay?

Is having zero-cross detection a must for inductive/capacitive loads, or does not make any difference?

[image]

Comment: All SSR are not the same. If the manufacturer says don’t use reactive loads then expect problems if you do. For SSRs where the manufacturer does specify reactive loads, they’re probably using different electronics internally to achieve that along with a cost.

Comment: You may modify it, adding snubber for instance.if it is home project, you may experiment. If industrial, choose suitable device.

Comment: SSR relays can use a triac or FETs as the switching device. Triacs are typically used for high-voltage AC such as mains, as they give you zero-crossing turn-off which reduces EMI from the load (not talking about contact EMI, there aren't any contacts in it).